# Is A Game Fullscreen Or Windowed?

Tags: c#, winforms, window, fullscreen

Is there anyway to know if a certain game is running on full screen or running as a window?

I need this because my application is for a game that can toggle between fullscreen and window mode and I need to act differently to each situation.

something like :

```
if (Fullscreen) {Act For Fullscreen} else {Act For Window Mode}
```

*The game isn't mine, it's another game. A real game.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying whether the game is yours or an external application. A few answers assume the former, where i think you mean the latter.

Comment: Please try this. I've tried it on games.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35582683/168345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that game is not written by you. You can use Win32 api http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetWindowPlacement

Answer (score 1):

won't this do?

```
if(WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
```

Comment: @user779444: What do you mean? If you are inside a method of your form class then exactly as I wrote (or `this.WindowState`). If not, then you have to have a form object - say it's myForm. Then you write `myForm.WindowState`

Answer (score 1):

It will probably depend on specific graphics technology you will be using rather than on WinForms API.

For example XNA (DirectX):

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(...); 

graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `WindowState` and `FormWindowState` enumeration?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate.aspx

A `Full Screen` application is a maximized window without borders.